# Unset Array based on key value

Tags: php, loops, foreach, unset

I have this array here let's call it $_products, my goal is to remove the array based on the key value of "activationdate" if it's greater than today's date.

```
{
    "id": "1388",
    "name": "June 2019 -  2014 Kate Hill & 2014 Pressing Matters",
    "image": "linkurl",
    "month": "June 2019",
    "activationdate": "2019-06-01",
    "wine1": "2014 Kate Hill Pinot Noir",
    "wine2": "2014 Pressing Matters Pinot Noir"
},

{   //I WANT TO REMOVE THIS ARRAY
    "id": "8421",
    "name": "December 2021 Releases: Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018 $65 & Milton Pinot Noir 2019 $38",
    "image": "linkurl",
    "month": "December 2021",
    "activationdate": "2021-12-03",
    "wine1": "Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018",
    "wine2": "Milton Pinot Noir 2019"
}
```

So for my PHP loop

```
$date_now = date('Y-m-d'); //get today's date with format e.g 2021-01-02
foreach( $_products as $month => $_product ) {

if( $_product['activationdate'] > $date_now  )
   unset($_products[$month]);
}
```

However, it doesn't unset the array?

Comment: You're comparing a date to a string. `$_product['activationdate'] > $date_now`

Comment: hmm, strange. I did try to compare the two with a true/false. It echoed 'true' but it doesn't remove the array. any suggestions?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have JSON feed and you convert that into array using json_decode?

Comment: First set item to `null`, then after loop, user `array_filter` to remove null values

Comment: Off-topic: Cannot Reproduce.

Comment: Add square braces to form valid json.  Typo. https://3v4l.org/8h1dX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I presume that you have JSON feed for example $product_feed like follows

```
$json = $json = '[
{
    "id": "1388",
    "name": "June 2019 -  2014 Kate Hill & 2014 Pressing Matters",
    "image": "linkurl",
    "month": "June 2019",
    "activationdate": "2019-06-01",
    "wine1": "2014 Kate Hill Pinot Noir",
    "wine2": "2014 Pressing Matters Pinot Noir"
},
{
    "id": "8421",
    "name": "December 2021 Releases: Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018 $65 & Milton Pinot Noir 2019 $38",
    "image": "linkurl",
    "month": "December 2021",
    "activationdate": "2021-12-03",
    "wine1": "Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018",
    "wine2": "Milton Pinot Noir 2019"
}
]';
```

I have converted that into PHP array using json_decode function like

```
$products = json_decode($json);
```

Next To compare with the current date I have converted current date to time string as follow

```
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
```

The main loop and unsetting task is as

```
foreach ($products as $month => $product) {
    if(strtotime($product->activationdate) > $current_date) { // Date comparison
        unset($products[$month]); // Here you made a mistake
    }
}
```

In this case what you've missed it you're trying to unset key where you supposed to unset array element with the key.

The full code with print before and after array deletion as follow:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "id": "1388",
        "name": "June 2019 -  2014 Kate Hill & 2014 Pressing Matters",
        "image": "linkurl",
        "month": "June 2019",
        "activationdate": "2019-06-01",
        "wine1": "2014 Kate Hill Pinot Noir",
        "wine2": "2014 Pressing Matters Pinot Noir"
    },
    {
        "id": "8421",
        "name": "December 2021 Releases: Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018 $65 & Milton Pinot Noir 2019 $38",
        "image": "linkurl",
        "month": "December 2021",
        "activationdate": "2021-12-03",
        "wine1": "Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018",
        "wine2": "Milton Pinot Noir 2019"
    }
]';
$products = json_decode($json);
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
print_r($products);
foreach ($products as $month => $product) {
    if(strtotime($product->activationdate) > $current_date) { // Date comparison
        unset($products[$month]); // Here you made a mistake
    }
}
print_r($products);
```

---

The output of the print_r is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1388
            [name] => June 2019 -  2014 Kate Hill & 2014 Pressing Matters
            [image] => linkurl
            [month] => June 2019
            [activationdate] => 2019-06-01
            [wine1] => 2014 Kate Hill Pinot Noir
            [wine2] => 2014 Pressing Matters Pinot Noir
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8421
            [name] => December 2021 Releases: Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018 $65 & Milton Pinot Noir 2019 $38
            [image] => linkurl
            [month] => December 2021
            [activationdate] => 2021-12-03
            [wine1] => Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018
            [wine2] => Milton Pinot Noir 2019
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1388
            [name] => June 2019 -  2014 Kate Hill & 2014 Pressing Matters
            [image] => linkurl
            [month] => June 2019
            [activationdate] => 2019-06-01
            [wine1] => 2014 Kate Hill Pinot Noir
            [wine2] => 2014 Pressing Matters Pinot Noir
        )

)
```

I hope this is what you're looking for! Cheers!

You can play around the code [here](https://paiza.io/projects/PLqSh5OeRRBoyO9pkCH7iw)

Comment: `strtotime()` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for creating this @Vantiya but unfortunately, I still couldn't make it work :/

Comment: @ccmanz Try this $date_now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); instead of $date_now = date('Y-m-d');
and in the loop use the same in if condition like if( strtotime($_product['activationdate']) > $date_now  )

Acutally both the date should be converted to unix timestamp to compare. I am sure that condition doesn't match in your code and hence unsent not performed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect variable inside loop.

replace

`unset($_products[$month]);`

with

```
unset($_product[$month]);
```

Comment: I did update this 

if( $_product['activationdate'] > $date_now ) unset( $_product[$month] ); it still doesn't remove the array. If I compare the values with a true/false it results in true but doesn't remove the array.

Comment: So this page should be closed as a Typo instead of answering?

Comment: @ccmanz, create a new array inside the loop and then put the fields in that array and check the new output

Comment: @mickmackusa though I did a typo mistake. I still could not get it working. My apologies

Comment: @VishalParkash I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($_products as $k=>$v ) 

if( $v->activationdate>$date_now) unset($_products[$k]);
```

You use `month` in the `foreach`, but this is also a key and is misleading.

The whole code:

```
<?php

$s = '[
{
    "id": "1388",
    "name": "June 2019 -  2014 Kate Hill & 2014 Pressing Matters",
    "image": "linkurl",
    "month": "June 2019",
    "activationdate": "2019-06-01",
    "wine1": "2014 Kate Hill Pinot Noir",
    "wine2": "2014 Pressing Matters Pinot Noir"
},
{
    "id": "8421",
    "name": "December 2021 Releases: Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018 $65 & Milton Pinot Noir 2019 $38",
    "image": "linkurl",
    "month": "December 2021",
    "activationdate": "2021-12-03",
    "wine1": "Apsley Gorge Pinot Noir 2018",
    "wine2": "Milton Pinot Noir 2019"
}
]';

$p=json_decode($s);

$date_now = date('Y-m-d'); //get today's date with format e.g 2021-01-02

foreach($p as $k=>$v ) if( $v->activationdate>$date_now) unset($p[$k]);

var_dump( $p);
?>
```

[Teh playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/35rJbtEWml2etQFZ)